# How do I split my textfile into a 2d array with delimiters in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, delimiter

My textfile contains contents such as:

```xml
1/1/2018;0;29;10
1/2/2018;0;16;1
1/3/2018;0;32;1
1/4/2018;0;34;15
1/5/2018;0;19;2
1/6/2018;0;21;2
```

Further down in the textfiles are decimals which is why I am trying to use double

```xml
1/29/2018;0.32;52;38
1/30/2018;0.06;44;21
```

I am trying to split up the semicolons and assign each value between the semicolons into a 2D array that contains 31 rows and 4 columns.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 2d array
    double[,] testarray = new double[31, 4];
    string inputFile = File.ReadAllText("testywesty.txt");
    char[] spearator = {';',' '};

    for (int row = 0; row < 31; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            string[] strlist = inputFile.Split(spearator);
            testarray [row,column] = double.Parse(strlist[column]);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that I have the right loop needed to insert my values into the 2d array, however, I am getting an error for my input and I believe it is because of the slashes.

Is my code sufficient for holding the text file's contents into my array? And how do I deal with the `'/'` characters?

Comment: `1/6/2018` does this look like it can be converted into a double? What i think you want to do is make a class, and parse each line into the class. The class would likely consist of a DateTime property, and a few doubles. you would most likely want to create a `List<T>` to hold it for your own sanity, instead of an array. Also there are libraries that do this for you, i.e csv parsers

Comment: Just to clarify - you want random strangers on internet to explain you what you want to do with the data you have? Not exactly sure if that will lead to positive experience... You may want to think of what you want to achieve and [edit] post accordingly... One obvious option is ignore date portion - but that does not seem like what you want...

Comment: for column[0] you can use:   var myDatetime = DateTime.Parse("1/5/2018", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); for col 1..3 you can use Your double.Parse()

Comment: It seems you have 4 columns, the first one being a `DateTime`, the second one a `float` or `double`  and the last two `int`. Is this correct?

Comment: What are you doing with the array? There might be better options out there than forcing everything into a 2d array of `double[,]`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be getting an error on the slashes because you're trying to convert them to doubles, which is not possible. One thing you can do is first convert them to a `DateTime` using the `Parse` method of that class, and then use the `ToOADate` method to convert it to a `double`. Note that if you need to convert it back, you can use the `DateTime.FromOADate` method as I've done in the output below.

Also, it might be helpful to use `File.ReadAllLines` to read the file into an array of strings, where each string is a file line (this assumes that each line contains the four parts you need as you've shown in the sample file contents in the question). This way each line represents a `row`, and then we can split that line to get our `columns`.

For example:

```
private static void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("testywesty.txt");
    var items = new double[lines.Length, 4];
    var delims = new[] {';', ' '};

    for (var line = 0; line < lines.Length; line++)
    {
        var parts = lines[line].Split(delims);
        var maxParts = Math.Min(parts.Length, items.GetLength(1));

        for (var part = 0; part < maxParts; part++)
        {
            if (part == 0)
            {
                // Parse first item to a date then use ToOADate to make it a double
                items[line, part] = DateTime.Parse(parts[part]).ToOADate();
            }
            else
            {
                items[line, part] = double.Parse(parts[part]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Show the output
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    for (var row = 0; row < items.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        for (var col = 0; col < items.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            result.Add(col == 0
                ? DateTime.FromOADate(items[row, col]).ToShortDateString()
                : items[row, col].ToString());
        }

        output.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", result));
    }
    MessageBox.Show(output.ToString(), "Results");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can read the data and parse it into an array. But since it is polymorphic the array needs to be of `object[,]` type. This is how I would approach this:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[,] array = ReadFileAsArray("testywesty.txt");            
    }

    static object[,] ReadFileAsArray(string file)
    {
        // how long is the file?
        // read it twice, once to count the rows 
        // and a second time to read each row in
        int rows = 0;

        var fs = File.OpenText(file);
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            fs.ReadLine();
            rows++;
        }
        fs.Close();

        var array = new object[rows, 4];
        fs = File.OpenText(file);
        int row = 0;
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            // read line
            var line = fs.ReadLine();
            // split line into string parts at every ';'
            var parts = line.Split(';');
            // if 1st part is date store in 1st column
            if (DateTime.TryParse(parts[0], out DateTime date))
            {
                array[row, 0] = date;
            }
            // if 2nd part is flaot store in 2nd column
            if (float.TryParse(parts[1], out float x))
            {
                array[row, 1] = x;
            }
            // if 3rd part is integer store in 3rd column
            if (int.TryParse(parts[2], out int a))
            {
                array[row, 2] = a;
            }
            // if 4rd part is integer store in 4rd column
            if (int.TryParse(parts[3], out int b))
            {
                array[row, 3] = b;
            }
            row++;
        }
        fs.Close();

        return array;
    }
}
```

But I feel this is clunky. If the data types represented by the file are predetermined than filling in a collection of a custom type feels more natural in `C#`, as you let the type handle its own data and parsing. Consider the example below:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyData> list = ReadFileAsEnumerable("testywesty.txt");

        Debug.WriteLine(MyData.ToHeading());
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }            
        // date        x    a    b   
        // 1/1/2018       0   29   10
        // 1/2/2018       0   16    1
        // 1/3/2018       0   32    1
        // 1/4/2018       0   34   15
        // 1/5/2018       0   19    2
        // 1/6/2018       0   21    2
        // 1/29/2018   0.32   52   38
        // 1/30/2018   0.06   44   21
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyData> ReadFileAsEnumerable(string file)
    {
        var fs = File.OpenText(file);
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            yield return MyData.Parse(fs.ReadLine());
        }
        fs.Close();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Stores a row of my data
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Mutable structures are evil. Make all properties read-only.
/// </remarks>
public struct MyData
{
    public MyData(DateTime date, float number, int a, int b)
    {
        this.Date = date;
        this.Number= number;
        this.A=a;
        this.B=b;
    }
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public float Number { get; }
    public int A { get; }
    public int B { get; }

    public static MyData Parse(string line)
    {
        // split line into string parts at every ';'
        var parts = line.Split(';');
        // if 1st part is date store in 1st column
        if (DateTime.TryParse(parts[0], out DateTime date)) { }
        // if 2nd part is flaot store in 2nd column
        if (float.TryParse(parts[1], out float number)) { }
        // if 3rd part is integer store in 3rd column
        if (int.TryParse(parts[2], out int a)) { }
        // if 4rd part is integer store in 4rd column
        if (int.TryParse(parts[3], out int b)) { }

        return new MyData(
            date,
            number,
            a,
            b);
    }
    public static string ToHeading()
    {
        return $"{"date",-11} {"x",-4} {"a",-4} {"b",-4}";
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Date.ToShortDateString(),-11} {Number,4} {A,4} {B,4}";
    }
}
```